# Function move_uploaded_file(); dont move the file

Tags: php

i'm try move file with php to mysql>data ubication for use LOAD DATA function for mysql, but the files dont move in the folder path

this is for upload a csv file in the database running Mysql with XAMPP and apache 7.3.1

```
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');

$carpeta = "C:/xampp/mysql/data/";

$n_archivo = $fecha.'-'.$_FILES['archivo_csv']['name'];

$nombre_fichero = substr($_FILES['archivo_csv']['name'],0,-4);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo_csv']['tmp_name'], $carpeta.$n_archivo);
```

I expect the file move to C:/xampp/mysql/data/"FILE_NAME" but the actual output is "Errorcode:2 'No such file or directory'`enter code here`

Comment: Maybe try using \\ instead of / in the $carpeta variable?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have solved the error by checking my configuration file for the apache php.ini server in the section of maximum load size for the files

Comment: Okay so the problem was that the file was too big to upload, and that made the error "Errorcode:2 'No such file or directory'"? You could add is_uploaded_file() to check it even more.

Answer (score 0):

try copy() function.

```
copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path);
```